# When to use a Map instead of a List in Java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I didn't get the sense of Maps in Java. When is it recommended to use a Map instead of a List?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Java map: An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>
> Java list: An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

The difference is that they are different.  Map is a mapping of key/values, a list of a list of items.

Comment: you forgot lists can contain duplicates

Comment: Is a List ordered?  Or does 'ordered' mean something different than 'sorted.'  Not trying to nitpick...

Comment: the java doc says ordered, I almost put the same thing Tony.

Comment: @Tony: Sorted != Ordered. For an ordered collection, the elements have an(y) ordering (which is obvious to the programmer, and usually can be manipulated by the programmer). Lists are ordered, e.g. each item in a LinkedList points to the next item. For sorted collections, the order of the items is determined by comparisions of the items, and always kept sorted.

Comment: A use case would be better than just the definition. I feel the OP knows definitions, but unable to visualise practical uses.

Answer (score 56):

Say you have a bunch of students with names and student IDs.   If you put them in a List, the only way to find the student with student_id = 300 is to look at each element of the list, one at a time, until you find the right student.

With a Map, you associate each student's ID and the student instance.  Now you can say, "get me student 300" and get that student back instantly.

Use a Map when you need to pick specific members from a collection.  Use a List when it makes no sense to do so.

Say you had exactly the same student instances but your task was to produce a report of all students' names.  You'd put them in a List since there would be no need to pick and choose individual students and thus no need for a Map.

Comment: +1 for not citing javadoc and providing illustrative example :)

Comment: that technically isn't correct.  If the student id maps to an index e.g. id 300 -> 299 [index] it is a constant time lookup

Comment: I didn't say it was, however the broader statement you made was less correct (from a theory perspective)

Comment: @Woot4Moo What if the student id was a string instead of a number?

Comment: @user2520215 what?

Comment: @Woot4Moo The student id 300 may map to 299, but in case the student id is string eg,ST01M, we wouldn't really be able to map it to an index of an array.

Comment: And who says student IDs have to conveniently map into an array? What if one ID is, say, 9 digits long?

Answer (score 4):

I thinks its a lot the question of how you want to access your data. With a map you can "directly" access your items with a known key, in a list you would have to search for it, evan if its sorted.

Compare:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
//Fill up the list
// Want to get object "peter"
for( MyObject m : list ) {
 if( "peter".equals( m.getName() ) {
    // found it
 }
}
```

In a map you can just type

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
// Fill map
MyObject getIt = map.get("peter");
```

If you have data to process and need to do it with all objects anyway, a list is what you want. If you want to process single objects with well known key, a map is better.
Its not the full answer (just my 2...) but I hope it might help you.

Answer (score 3):

A map is used as an association of a key and a value. With a list you have basically only values.
The indexes in List are always int, whereas in Map you can have another Object as a key.

---

**Resources :**

- [sun.com - Introduction to the Collections Framework, Map](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html#MapInterface)

Answer (score 3):

When you want to map instead of list.  The names of those interfaces have meaning, and you shouldn't ignore it.

Use a map when you want your data structure to represent a mapping for keys to values.  Use a list when you want your data to be stored in an arbitrary, ordered format.

Comment: This is like using a word in it's own definition. This is not a very helpful answer...

Comment: No, it's pointing out that the names of those interfaces have meaning, and you shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: Added your comment and a bit more information, then removed my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your performance concerns.  A Map more explicitly a HashMap will guarantee O(1) on inserts and removes.  A List has at worst O(n) to find an item.  So if you would be so kind as to elaborate on what your scenario is we may help more.

Answer (score 3):

Its probably a good idea to revise [Random Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) Vs [Sequential Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_access) [Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure). They both have different run time complexities and suitable for different type of contexts.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` and `List` serve different purpose.

`List` holds collection of items. Ordered (you can get item by index).

`Map` holds mapping key -> value. E.g. map person to position: "JBeg" -> "programmer". And it is unordered. You can get value by key, but not by index.

Comment: Treemap implementation of a map is not unordered.

Comment: sorted != ordered

Answer (score 0):

Maps store data objects with unique keys,therefore provides fast access to stored objects. You may use ConcurrentHashMap in order to achieve concurrency in multi-threaded environments.
Whereas lists may store duplicate data and you have to iterate over the data elements in order to access a particular element, therefore provide slow access to stored objects.
You may choose any data structure depending upon your requirement.