# java collections vs map in collections framework

Tags: java, collections

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html there are two top level interfaces called collection and map.

Whats the exact reason for separating these two ?

Is it that all key value data structures implement the map interface and all others implement the collections interface ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, That's correct! Check all the `List` classes and then check all the `Map` related classes.

and there is this awesome discussion, ob this question

[List vs Map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770613/list-vs-map-in-java)

**Visually**

This is a **collection**, by this you know that the books are there and it's in order like 0,1,2,3...

[image]

But in a **Map**, the books are in memory unordered but for the computer's convenience it has a key to find the books, like in a library.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A `Map` is a structure that has unique keys mapping to values. A `Collection` is just a grouping of multiple values with no specific key.

You can do the same comparison between a `List` and a `Map` to see the differences. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770613/list-vs-map-in-java) deals with these differences.