# Best Java Data Structure: Map or List?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, comparator

I need insight into a fundamental quandary: List or Map?

I have two numeric fields that correspond to a key (string). I need to pass a large number of these records. I can either make an object of all three with a Comparator on the key and list them, or I can make an object of the two fields and hash (probably LinkedHashMap) it on the key. Can anyone point me to pros/cons of each option?

Comment: Can anyone point me to pros/cons of each option? ---> http://Google.com

Comment: Fair enough. I should have specified I'm curious about storage overhead, don't particularly care about access times which is most of what I was seeing. But I'll take another look.

Comment: The comment above clearly indicates that the questioner has made *some* effort. Now, do all of the unoriginal, unfunny and most importantly unconstructive "go use Google" comments get removed? Do all of those who decided to downvote without reading retract their downvotes? Probably not ...

Comment: How are the keys to be sorted? Based on insertion order or something else (e.g. alphabetical)?

Comment: Sorted by insertion order in some cases; possibly other forms like least-greatest on one of the fields. But the sort would only be needed once and not need to be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about looking up the entries *at all,* and you only care about memory consumption, use a `List`.  See https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures for information about memory consumption of various data structures.

If you need efficient lookup from some specific key that is *not* a consecutive integer index, use a `Map`.

Comment: Cool resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question, here is the answer they accepted.

> Java map: An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>
> Java list: An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.
>
> The difference is that they are different. Map is a mapping of key/values, a list of a list of items.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770635/1146562

Comment: This answer is slightly less relevant for me as I had suggested a LinkedHashMap (ordered). Duplicates, on the other hand, are a good point.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon how you want to retrieve the records.

If you need relatively random access, the extra memory overhead required for the Map structure will allow you to have constant-time access independent of the order that they are inserted.

If you're only going to retrieve the records in a fixed order, the List is a better choice here as it will be lighter weight in terms of memory usage.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526596/memory-overhead-of-java-hashmap-compared-to-arraylist) relates to the memory footprint of either structure in Java.