# Can someone explain how this works please?

Tags: java, class, jlabel

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = label.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

I have seen this code at least 100+ times today and i have tried it 100+ times and every single time it does not work. I am trying to underline text in a JLabel and this is the only block of code that i have found at all, and everyone else on stackoverflow seems to understand this, except me??? Is Map a class?

Comment: Technically, Map is an interface, but you can think of it as a class.  I imagine attributes is a HashMap, which implements Map.

Comment: @billjamesdev so Map attributes = font.getAttributes(); is the initialization of the interface?

Comment: Well, no.. attributes contains all the attributes of the font in a "list" of key-value pairs.  Whereas a List is like this ["value1", "value2"], a Map is like this [ "attrName": "attrValue", "attrName2": "attr2Value" ].  Map values are retrieve by key ("attrName" above), rather than by index (as with a List)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770613/list-vs-map-in-java

Comment: And what you have above in your question works fine for me.  Are you seeing the label at all, just non-underlined?  Or is the label not showing at all (in which case, it's probably because you didn't add it to a view)?

Comment: @billjamesdev thanks that kinda makes sense. I can still see the label, but the thing is i have no idea how to use the code above (i know i sound very clueless, i am a beginning programming student in high school) because i'm not sure how to use attributes or map. If it helps: my Jlabel is named 'topCaption' and the JPanel that i am adding it all to is called 'viewerWindow' thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to your question and comments, you have code somewhere that creates a JLabel named topCaption, adds it to a JPanel called viewWindow, and you can see the label as a results.

So somewhere you have:

```
JLabel topCaption = new JLabel( you may have some stuff here );
```

Right after that, do this:

```
Font font = topCaption.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
topCaption.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Also, I might suggest you need to do more reading before you continue with this, as knowledge of what a Map is, etc. is pretty basic to most UI programming, and you're going to continue to have trouble like this without some fundamentals under your belt.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I actually figured out why it wasn't working and its actually kind of embarassing thinking that i needed to search online for it. oh well thanks so much anywas